# SaveChanges not setting value, selecting existing value instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When trying to commit a modified entry to the database, Entity Framework is selecting values for two properties as opposed to setting them.

The code to commit the entity to the database is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Till till)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string username = User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

        till.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        till.ModifiedByUid_FK = db.Users.Where(m => m.Name.ToLower() == username.ToLower()).First().UserUid_PK;

        db.Entry(till).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index/" + (int)Session["siteid"]);
    }
    ViewBag.SiteUid_FK = new SelectList(db.Sites, "SiteUid_PK", "Name", till.SiteUid_FK);
    ViewBag.ModifiedByUid_FK = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserUid_PK", "EHLogin", till.ModifiedByUid_FK);
    ViewBag.CreatedByUid_FK = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserUid_PK", "EHLogin", till.CreatedByUid_FK);
    return View(till);
}
```

When viewed in the profiler, it looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Till]
set [NetworkId] = @0, [MID] = @1, [SiteUid_FK] = @2, [Location] = null, [MasterTillNo] = @3,
    [IsMaster] = @4, [IsBackOffice] = @5, [IsCurrent] = @6, [ModifiedByUid_FK] = @7, 
    [CreatedByUid_FK] = @8, [ProcessFiles] = @9
where ([TillUid_PK] = @10)
select [ModifiedDate], [CreatedDate]
from [dbo].[Till]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [TillUid_PK] = @10',N'@0 varchar(50),@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 bit,@5 bit,@6 
    bit,@7 int,@8 int,@9 bit,@10 int',
    @0='',@1='',@2=4,@3=42,@4=1,@5=0,@6=1,@7=4,@8=1,@9=1,@10=699
```

I'm guessing there's some property of the field in the database that EF uses to determine this functionality but I can't figure out what it is. If anyone has any information that'd be fantastic :)

---

## Edit 1

Using Ibrahim's answer below, results in relatively similar SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'declare @p int
update [dbo].[Till]
set @p = 0
where ([TillUid_PK] = @0)
select [ModifiedDate], [CreatedDate]
from [dbo].[Till]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [TillUid_PK] = @0',N'@0 int',@0=687
```

Comment: Normally, you'd do a lookup for the entity, update the values with those from your POSTed model, then perform an update.  I've not seen it done the way you're doing it - I'm not even sure it would work, but it's certainly not advisable.

Comment: That's the 'out of the box' way that ASP.NET MVC does it :), I don't see why it's wrong, can you explain?

Comment: Apart from the fact that it doesn't work? Well for starters you shouldn't expose data entities in Views.

Comment: I'm not disputing that it *is* wrong, I am asking you to explain yourself. It's nonconstructive to tell me it's wrong and not tell me why, when I clearly do not understand.

Comment: I didn't actually say it was wrong, I just said I'd never seen an update done like that before. Anyway, The answer from @Ibrahim is the way to do it.

Comment: Not trying to argue, I just realise I'm doing something incorrectly and wanna learn how to not do it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

This typically happens when properties have the data annotation

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

or the fluent mapping

```
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
```

or the `StoreGeneratedPattern` is `Computed` in the edmx file.

I'd guess that there is a trigger or a default value on `ModifiedDate` and `CreatedDate` on the columns in the database. Maybe it's even useless to set them in your application code.

Comment: I had a feeling that was it, but I removed it from the EDMX file and it didn't change anything. I removed the DefaultValue on `ModifiedDate` in the database then updated the EDMX, removed `StoreGeneratedPattern` and no dice. :(

Comment: That's weird. The edmx is all information EF has about the model. Even if there was a default value in the database, EF wouldn't query it if the StoreGeneratedPattern didn't stipulate it.

Comment: Yeah I think if I delete the EDMX and re-add it, it'll probably work, but I hacked around this issue and can't be bothered today. If I change it in the future and it works due to this, I'll make sure to come back and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have had bad luck with the following also:

```
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

So I suggest trying to do the following:

```
//Get the existing Till
var existingTill = db.Tills.Find(till.TillId);

//Save changes for only changed properties
db.Entry(existingTill).CurrentValues.SetValues(till);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Does this method also require that you change the state of the entity to Modified?

Comment: Nope. Just fit the above code in your action and it should work.

Comment: Same difference, it still selects the two date fields from the table instead.

Comment: Notice that the SELECT is being preceded by an UPDATE. Check whether the record was updated in the database or not.

Comment: It is not. EF is generating SQL that *never* sets those two values, I don't care about `CreatedDate` but I need to be able to change `ModifiedDate` for obvious reasons.

Comment: There must something else wrong here. Try fetching the existing `Till` entity from db (from matching Id) then try explicitly setting the `ModifiedDate` and then call `SaveChanges`. See if the changes are reflected in the Db.

Comment: The value is set before SaveChanges. Can screenshot if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65768/discussion-between-lbrahim-and-sippy).